# Calculated field gives "formula refers to a column that does not exist" error for auto increment

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, site-column, auto-increment

I'm working on SharePoint Online (new excperiance) and I've created a document library at the *Site Content Type*s. For that type I'll have a column with auto increments and starting with `TN`. For this I create a column type of *Calculated (calculation based on other columns)*.

[image]

At the *Additional Column Settings*, I'm using this formula

```
= "TN" & [ID]
```

and *The data type returned from this formula is*: *Single line of text*.

[image]

But when I save, I've got next error:

> **Sorry, something went wrong:** The formula refers to a column that does not exist. Check the formula for spelling mistakes or change the non-existing column to an existing column.

I've added a hidden column `ID` to the list.

[image]

Did I something wrong? I've seen on [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72537/auto-number-column-in-sharepoint-list) that my formula is correct.

Comment: What is the internal name of ID column?

Comment: @GaneshSanap: I've found that `ID` was a part of a custom group I created. I think this is wrong and deleted that. I don't use that. But now I don't have any identifier anymore...

Comment: it is not best practice to use sharepoint default `ID` column in calculated column formula. To Auto increment field. you can use workflow and set the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SharePoint default ID column in the calculated columns is not good option because ID will created after item added successfully in the list.

Even thought ID column is not in the list of "Insert Column" fields while creating formula, IDs can work in calculated columns just by writing `[ID]` in formula. But, they are unreliable as the calculated column will get updated only if the item is edited/changed.

**Solution**:

**Use Workflow** : If you need to use the ID column in a calculation, the best approach is to do the calculation in a workflow and set a column to the value returned by the calculation.